# How to prevent TypeScript from including .d.ts import in the output?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

I have installed a .d.ts file (namely, type definitions for [p2.js](https://github.com/schteppe/p2.js) library) as external (non-global) `typings` module with the following command:

```
typings install p2=github:schteppe/p2.js/index.d.ts#9d56924
```

I then use it in my TypeScript code like this:

```
import * as p2 from 'p2';
```

This import appears in the compiled javascript:

```
var p2 = require('p2');
```

But, obviously, I do not need it there, since the `p2` external module contains only type definitions, not actual code. I then run `webpack` on the TypeScript's output and it fails to compile with

```
...Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'p2'...
```

What is the right way to use this external module so that TypeScript and my IDE (Atom with atom-typescript plugin) see the definitions, but no `require` call for it gets included in the TypeScript output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webpack supports configuring externals.

In your case this would be
`externals: [ { "p2": true}]`

More info on handling externals in the webpack documentation:
webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals.

Edit: updated with new information from comments

Comment: The whole problem is that it is a non-global (external) typing, thus it has to be imported.

Comment: Ah i see, webpack supports configuring externals.

in your case this would be  

    `externals: [
        {
            "p2": true
        }
    ]`

http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals. Let me know if it works then i will update the original answer.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. Still feels a bit hacky (typescript does not include declarations in its output, no reason to include references to modules containing only declarations), but I understand why it works this way. I will accept this answer if no other (cleaner) solutions will be proposed.

Answer (score -1):

Set `compileOnSave : false` in your tsconfig.json.

*See https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/faq.md#i-dont-want-atom-typescript-compiling-my-js*

Comment: But this just disables the TypeScript compilation. Everything worked fine with two-step build process (TypeScript -> JavaScript followed by JavaScript -> Bundled JavaScript with typescript and webpack repsectively) until I decided to use a non-global typedef module. Is using ts-loader the only way to get it working?